# Changing radio buttons to images - a little help please?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to change the radio buttons on this page to images
http://www.pazzle.co.uk/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=6_1&products_id=3

I am using this tutorial to do it:
http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

This script does not seem to work for me, are there any better solutions for changing radio buttons to images?

Answer (score 2):

That tutorial is quite old it doesnt have keyboard support and the script seems quite complex... Try this jQuery plugin [jq-customRadioCheck](https://github.com/elclanrs/jq-customRadioCheck).

You'll need an image sprite such as this one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wbG0.png.

**HTML:**

```
<label><input type="checkbox"/>Checkbox</label>
<label><input type="radio"/>Radio</label>
```

**jQuery:**

```
;(function(){
$.fn.customRadioCheck = function() {

  return this.each(function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    var $span = $('<span/>');

    $span.addClass('custom-'+ ($this.is(':checkbox') ? 'check' : 'radio'));
    $this.is(':checked') && $span.addClass('checked'); // init
    $span.insertAfter($this);

    $this.parent('label').addClass('custom-label')
      .attr('onclick', ''); // Fix clicking label in iOS
    // hide by shifting left
    $this.css({ position: 'absolute', left: '-9999px' });

    // Events
    $this.on({
      change: function() {
        if ($this.is(':radio')) {
          $this.parent().siblings('label')
            .find('.custom-radio').removeClass('checked');
        }
        $span.toggleClass('checked', $this.is(':checked'));
      },
      focus: function() { $span.addClass('focus'); },
      blur: function() { $span.removeClass('focus'); }
    });
  });
};
}());
```

**CSS:**

```
.custom-label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: .8em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.custom-radio,
.custom-check {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -.15em; /* Adjust to for best fit */
    margin: 0 .4em;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: url(customRadioCheck.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
.custom-radio { background-position: 0 -20px; }
.custom-check.focus { background-position: -20px 0; }
.custom-radio.focus { background-position: -20px -20px; }
.custom-check.checked { background-position: -40px 0; }
.custom-radio.checked { background-position: -40px -20px; }
.custom-check.checked.focus { background-position: -60px 0; }
.custom-radio.checked.focus { background-position: -60px -20px; }
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/BQp2F/

Comment: Thanks you for assisting me. I have saved the JQuery you provided as  **jscript_customradio.js** which is being loaded externally. I then added your CSS to the end of my website stylesheet and finally saved the sprite into the same directory as the stylsheet.

-
If you go to my page... http://www.pazzle.co.uk/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=6_1&products_id=3 you can see it didn't work. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Also, if you take the jsfiddle demo and copy my page source code in there instead of the test html, you will see it does not seem to work?

Comment: This is a screenshot of my web page showing that the .js and the .css are being loaded with no errors yet no effect on the radio buttons:
http://i50.tinypic.com/o0qdde.png... - I still think there is a deeper issue as my source code does not work in the JSfiddle demo.

Comment: I would start by fixing other more important things than trivial checkboxes. Your website is a mess, you're loading jQuery 3 times (multiple versions), you have inline scripts and styles, bad copy/pasted scripts, and the list goes on. I suggest you fix all that first or your site will end up slow and hard to maintain.

Comment: your absolutely right, that is my next priority. I will however need to fix this issue and since we are on the topic im wondering if you could advise as to why the script isn't working with my site.

Comment: Ok I have spent the last hour or so cleaning up my code and removing unused scripts. Are you still available to assist me with the code you have provided?